# why is Collections.sort() is not working?

Tags: java, sorting

I am new to java. I am writing a code which sorts the given pairs on the basis of it's first letter. I am using `Collections.sort()` to sort the pairs but somehow it's not being sorted. I am unable to figure out what's causing the problem. Please check the code below. Thanks.

```
package main.java.practice;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;

public class StringChain {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<Pair> arr = new ArrayList<>();
    arr.add(new Pair('i', 'a'));
    arr.add(new Pair('a', 'f'));
    arr.add(new Pair('g', 'h'));
    arr.add(new Pair('f', 'g'));
    arr.add(new Pair('z', 'i'));

    Collections.sort(arr, new Comparator<Pair>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Pair o1, Pair o2) {
            if (o1.a < o2.b) return 1;
            else return 0;
        }
    });

    // Expected output should be
    //   a f
    //   f g
    //   g h
    //   i a
    //   z i
    for( Pair x : arr) {
        System.out.println(x.a  + " " + x.b);
    }
    // Actual output
    //  i a
    //  a f
    //  g h
    //  f g
    //  z i

  }

}

class Pair {

    char a;
    char b;

    Pair() {};
    Pair(char a, char b) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }
 }
```

Comment: You're missing an `return -1`.

Comment: You should rather implement your `Pair` object with `Comparable` interface and override method `compareTo(Pair anotherPair)`.

Comment: Thanks for the valuable replies! I got it now! :)

Comment: You need to read the Javadoc for `Comparator`, understand its preconditions and postconditions, and code accordingly.

Answer (score 5):

You have wrong implementation of compare method.

Try it:

```
Collections.sort(arr, new Comparator<Pair>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Pair o1, Pair o2) {
            return Character.compare(o1.a, o2.b);
        }
    });
```

Also if you use java 8 you can update code as follow:

```
 arr.sort((o1, o2) -> Character.compare(o1.a, o2.a));
```

Answer (score 3):

Comparator should return 1,-1,0

```
new Comparator<Pair>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Pair o1, Pair o2) {
            if (o1.a < o2.b){ return 1;}
            else if(o1.a > o2.a) {return -1 }
            else {return 0;}
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to cover 3 possible options in the comparable implementation:

```
 when (o1.a < o2.a) 
 when (o1.a > o2.a) 
 when (o1.a = o2.a)
```

but you are basically omitting one that is why the code is not working as it should